# Paladin Hoss is dead. Now what?

Tags: fallout-3

In Fallout 3 I met Paladin Hoss and another guy fighting super mutants, and they recruited me to follow them in finding their teammate. But after a minute or so, he got blasted and died by one of the mutants. Is there any way to replay the mission as it seems to be a good opportunity for farming? (good xp, items etc.) I play the ps3 version, so no console commands are available I believe.

Comment: Reload a save where he's still alive?

Comment: Yep I was thinking if there would be any other option. Like quest-respawning or something like that.. But no huh?

Comment: No, there is no in-game way to reset a quest. If console commands aren't an option you'll have to reload or just accept the result.

Comment: thanks, that was informative. If you want, post it as an answer, so I can choose it like a correct one.

Comment: Ok, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no in-game way to reset quests in Fallout 3. If a quest specific NPC dies, the only ways to do the quest would be using console commands (which, as you said you don't have) or loading a previous save.